# $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+n\sin^2{nx}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I am stuck to a problem, evaluate the limit : $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+n\sin^2{nx}} $

I have started in this way :
\begin{align*}
&\hspace{0.5cm} -1\leq \sin nx\leq 1\\
&\implies 0\leq \sin^2{nx}\leq 1\\
&\implies 0\leq n\sin^2{nx}\leq n\\
&\implies 1\leq 1+n\sin^2{nx}\leq 1+n\\
& \implies \frac{1}{1+n} \leq \frac{1}{1+n\sin^2{nx}} \leq 1
\end{align*}
Please help me how to proceed now.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really mean $\lim_{x \to \infty}$ and not $\lim_{n \to \infty}$? If so, then the limit doesn't exist unless $n = 0$.

Comment: I meant $x\to\infty.$ Can you please explain your point of view ,why the limit does not exist.

Comment: Sure, if $n$ is a nonzero constant, then as $x$ increases, $\sin^2(nx)$ oscillates between $0$ and $1$, hence the denominator of the fraction oscillates between $1$ and $1+n$. So $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1 + n \sin^2 nx}$ oscillates between $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+n}$ and $1$ as $x \to \infty$. You can see this by [plotting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1%2F%281+%2B+5*sin%5E2%285x%29%29) the function for some specific value of $n$ (I chose $n=5$ in the linked plot).

Comment: It's really straight forward. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Case 1:** $x=m\pi$ for $m\in \mathbb N$. Then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+n\sin^2{nx}}=\frac 1 1=1$$

**Case 2:** $x= m\pi\sqrt 2$ for $m\in \mathbb N$. Then
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{1+n\sin^2{nx}}\neq \frac 1 1$$

So, there are two subsequences which do not converge to the same limit.

So, the limit does not exist.

Comment: How can $x$ be some fixed value such as $m \pi$ if you're taking $\lim_{x \to \infty}$?

Comment: @Bungo Instead of taking $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)$, we are using $\lim_{m\to \infty} f(m\pi)$

Comment: @Bungo The sequential limit of $f$ as $x$ tends to $p$ is $L$ if, for every sequence $\{xn\}$ in $X − \{p\}$ that converges to $p$, the sequence $\{f(xn)\}$ converges to $L$. Here, I showed that there are two sequences which converge to different limit. Check "sequentia; definition of limit" for further information.

Comment: Understood..thank you

Comment: This approach is reasonable, but you haven't really defined the sequence used for case 2. This matters because you can certainly find sequences for which $x_n$ is never a multiple of $\pi$, but becomes arbitrarily close to multiples of $\pi$ as $n$ increases. (For example, $x_n = n\pi + 1/n$.) In that case the limit would still be $1$.

Comment: @Bungo I just showed that there are two sequences that converge to two different limits. That's enough to prove that the limit does not exist.

Comment: @user490489 You are welcome :)

Comment: In case 1, you showed that there is a sequence that converges to $1$. In case 2, you did not define a sequence at all. Depending on what sequence you use for case 2, the limit may or may not be $0$.

Comment: @Bungo I was going very informal. I placed an edit now. Is it fine?

Comment: @SayanDutta I think you run into problems due to equidistribution: there will be values of $m$ for which $m\pi\sqrt{2}$ is very close to a multiple of $\pi$, so I think the limit will not exist in that case. Which is OK for showing that the overall limit doesn't exist, but the limit wouldn't be $0$. In fact, no matter what, the limit won't be $0$, because the denominator can't approach $\infty$: it is bounded between $1$ and $1+n$ as the OP showed in the question. ($n$ is a fixed constant, we are taking the limit with respect to $x$, not $n$).

Comment: @Bungo Yes, true. Thanks for pointing it out. Just note that $\sin (mn\pi\sqrt 2)$ will never be $0$ as $\sqrt 2$ is irrational.